# Double encryption with Cloudflare SSL certificate + nginx letsencrypt certificate?

Tags: ssl, nginx, encryption, https, cloudflare

In `cloudflares` cryptography settings I have set SSL to `Full (Strict)` and the `Universal SSL Status` is on `Active Certificate` as you can see:

---

[image]

---

But the thing is I am using also a certificate on my server by `letsencrypt`/`certbot`, which also works If I deactivate `cloudflare`, so I wonder if there is now some kind of double encryption?

```
nginx(ssl) --> cloudflare(ssl) --> enduser
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no double encryption in the form of two encryptions inside each other. Instead there is one encryption between browser and Cloudflare and another one between Cloudflare and nginx. Both Cloudflare and nginx have access to the plain (unencrypted) data. The browser will only see and validate the certificate from Cloudflare while Cloudflare will see and validate the certificate from LetsEncrypt (served from nginx).

Comment: Thank you. Would it make more sense to deactivate ssl on nginx for performance reasons?

Comment: @saitam: Given that the communication between Cloudflare and your nginx goes over the untrusted internet the connection should also be protected by TLS.